# jqueryui remove styling applied to buttons in modal form

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Im a complete beginner with jquery and need some help please.

Im using jqueryui, Im using the modal form: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Ive got this working fine, However I want it so that a regular looking hyperlink can invoke this dialog. Anything I use just appears as the "create new user" like from the example above.

How can I remove all this styling, and just make a regular unstyled hyperlink invoke the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it actually much easier to do something like this:
Login

Answer (score 0):

The button's classes are as follows:

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default
```

You can find these in CSS and change the styles to fit your design :)

OR you can override them by putting them further down teh cascade (Nearer the bottom of teh CSS file) and this will override any default CSS styles.

Comment: is there a way i could can just invoke the dialog itself? Im finding it very cumbersome going through the css file, as there are too many references to these classes.

Comment: That depends on the way it is invoked, you'd have to dig through the plugin code to see what fires the form to display, the ID or one of the classes.